# Commit an entire Netbeans project on sourceforge

Tags: netbeans, sourceforge

I have my own PHP project in NetBeans. Afterwards I have registered a sourceforge account. Now I would use sf's git repository for versioning my code.
What I need now is to send the entire project on the repository, using netbeans. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on SourceForge's latest platform i.e. Allura, you first need to create a Git repository on SourceForge.

(You might have already done this when you first made project)
Following are the step to create git repository on it.
1) Log in to SourceForge
2) Go to Admin
3) Click on Tools
4) Click on Git. At this point, it will ask for Label and mount point for it. Enter those information. Once you finish it should create a new tab on top menu with whatever label name you provided. Let's say you named it 'Code' for now.
5) Click on 'Code' label and it would show you following instruction to push the code.

```
// First time using Git
cd <your_local_project_dir>
git init
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin ssh://<your_sourceforge_username>@git.code.sf.net/p/<your_project_name_on_sourceforge>/<mount_point_name_you_provide_in_step4>
git push origin master

// Existing Repository
cd <your_local_project_dir>
git remote add origin ssh://<your_sourceforge_username>@git.code.sf.net/p/<your_project_name_on_sourceforge>/<mount_point_name_you_provide_in_step4>
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to take a look at NetBeans' Git support;
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#initialize
It's built into the IDE so there's no plugin to install.